# Python 3: How to add a function to a Python class of a library?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I am using a class `A` from an open-source library.

I want to add a function `fn` to `A` without changing the source of the library, so let's say the function `fn` is available only in my project.

Is it possible? If so, how could I do that?

Thanks

Comment: `Add a function to A`: can you please clarify with a small example? E.g. do you want to add a method, a class method, or something else? What have you tried?

Comment: You have to modify the opensource class method or Add new method in particular opensource class

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add a method to one class the I think proper way to do that is to create class B that inherits from class A and there you can add the method. 
Something like

```
import open_source_library

class B(open_source_library.A):
    def my_fn():
         .....
```

Answer (score 1):

***Problem***

```
# a.py module
def print_message(msg):
    print(msg)

# b.py module
from a import print_message
def execute():
    print_message("Hello")

# c.py module which will be executed
import b
b.execute()
```

***Answer***

```
import a

def _new_print_message(message):
    print("NEW: " + message)

a.print_message = _new_print_message

import b
b.execute()
```

You have to first import a, then override the function and then import b so that it would use the a module that is already imported (and changed).